# Android Sockets - Client side IOException

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to connect to a simple Java server on my computer (in the future a true server, but I'm just learning how to program with sockets first. When I try to connect, the application on the phone throws an IOException. However, on the emulator, it does NOT.

I do have:

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

included in the manifest. And here's the code block that's executed when I hit open:

```
try {
  responseField.setText("Opening socket...");
  Socket socket = new Socket(getIP(),Integer.parseInt(getPort()));
  responseField.setText("Socket opened. Initializing out...");
  out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
  responseField.setText("Done. Initializing in...");
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  responseField.setText("Done.");
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
  responseField.setText("NumberFormatException");
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
  responseField.setText("UnknownHostException");
} catch (IOException e1) {
  responseField.setText("IOException");
}
```

Comment: What are getIP() and getPort() returning?

Comment: Did you make sure you have wifi/3G running?

Comment: Where does it fail, and what does the error say?

Comment: It fails when trying to make socket. "Opening socket..." is the last thing printed. And the problem seems to be in the EVO's weak Wi-Fi signal. One and two bars is not enough to surf the web apparently, so one can expect this to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that a weak Wi-Fi signal is causing error. I tried to surf the web (Google, CNN, etc.) afterward, and I could not. So I will just have to test on the emulator for now, or in a stronger signal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that the server end uses a ServerSocket and uses the ServerSocker.accept() method?

Comment: Yes, the emulator connects, send and receives perfectly

Comment: So it seems that a weak Wi-Fi signal is causing error. I tried to surf the web (Google, CNN, etc.) afterward, and I could not. So I will just have to test on the emulator for now, or in a stronger signal. Thanks.

Comment: I would also recommend very good error handling/notification to the user so that purchasers of your app know why it fails - explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, A more rebust application, will of course be developed, but now I know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to connect to the web before (I am assuming) but not after, then its not a problem with the wifi strength. Also depending on place you are surfing, the wifi router may have been configured not to allow such connections. Try to ping your server IP using a different computer within the same network and see whether you can ping. Emulator will work since the server is running on the localhost.